# Почему код в R выполняется так долго?

Tags: r

Работаю с R. Пытаюсь на своем компьтере запустить пример с данного сайта http://uc-r.github.io/gbm_regression.

```
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(
  shrinkage = c(.01, .1, .3),
  interaction.depth = c(1, 3, 5),
  n.minobsinnode = c(5, 10, 15),
  bag.fraction = c(.65, .8, 1), 
  optimal_trees = 0,               # a place to dump results
  min_RMSE = 0                     # a place to dump results
)
random_index <- sample(1:nrow(ames_train), nrow(ames_train))
random_ames_train <- ames_train[random_index, ]

# grid search 
for(i in 1:nrow(hyper_grid)) {
  
  # reproducibility
  set.seed(123)
  
  # train model
  gbm.tune <- gbm(
    formula = Sale_Price ~ .,
    distribution = "gaussian",
    data = random_ames_train,
    n.trees = 5000,
    interaction.depth = hyper_grid$interaction.depth[i],
    shrinkage = hyper_grid$shrinkage[i],
    n.minobsinnode = hyper_grid$n.minobsinnode[i],
    bag.fraction = hyper_grid$bag.fraction[i],
    train.fraction = .75,
    n.cores = NULL, # will use all cores by default
    verbose = FALSE
  )
```

dataset из kaggle соревнование на предсказание цены дома.
random_ames_train это 1022 строки и 81 переменная.
Сказано, что это должно выполнится примерно за 30 минут.Уже прошло больше 3 часов.
Мой ноут слабый. Он вообще может это выполнить?
Если да, то, как вы думаете, сколько это может занять времени?
Я много, где спрашивала, но пока что ответ нигде не получила. Если вопрос поставлен глупо, напишите, пожалуйста об это в комменте.

На фото характеристики ноута
[image: На фото характеристики ноута]

Comment: Обучение модели на CPU - уже не самая лучшая идея, а обучение таковой на Intel Celeron - идея так и вовсе кошмарная :)